# Creating a proton-sized black hole

Tags: black-holes, estimation

I'm a high school student just wondering if my logic is correct. The values I've used are from a quick Google search so it's possible they are inaccurate.

The average density of a black hole is $2\times 10^{19}\text{ kg m}^{-3}$. The radius of a proton is $0.85\times 10^{-15}\text{ m}$. The volume of a proton is $4/3\pi r^3=2.57\times 10^{-15}\text{ m}^3$ and the mass is $1.67\times 10^{-27}\text{ kg}$.

Since
$$\text{density}=\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{volume}}$$
the mass of proton-sized black hole should be $51400\text{ kg}$.

So this implies that if I could fit something with a mass of 51400 kg into the volume of a proton, I could create a black hole?

Also, $$\frac{51400}{1.67\times 10^{-27}}=3.08\times10^{31}$$
so this means $3.08\times10^{31}$ protons fit into the volume of one proton can make a black hole. I understand that this is a huge number, but with a hadron collider is this possible on a smaller scale?

Comment: at the dimensions of a proton one has to use quantum mechanics. related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole

Comment: Your mass value for a 0.85 fm BH is too small. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665807/is-there-a-point-where-the-matter-goes-from-trying-to-expand-to-being-a-black-ho#comment1492795_665807

Comment: Keep in mind also the theoretical formula for lifetime of (small) black holes.  It gets messy fast:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole